# How does apply-template order affect the attributes on the parent node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I ran into an issue regarding attributes on a node not showing when the `<xsl:apply-templates>` is used during an `<xsl:copy>`. I wanted to add a child node within my copy, at the top. However, I found that when I did the added node, followed by

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
```

I ended up with no attributes on the parent node.

Code Examples:

**Message to be Transformed**

```
<XMLMessage>
    <Name>QueryResponse</Name>
    <Content>       
        <Object status="Approved">
            <Slot name="languageCode">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>en-us</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Slot>                 
        </Object>
    </Content>
</XMLMessage>
```

This first XSLT results in no attributes coming across with the `<Object>`. My end goal was to have the added `<Slot>` above the languageCode slot, but I end up with no `@Status` attribute on the `<Object>` tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="//Object[not(Slot/@name='AddedValue')]">      
    <xsl:copy>
        <Slot name="AddedValue">
            <ValueList>
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Value to Add'"/>
                </Value>
            </ValueList>
        </Slot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<XMLMessage>
    <Name>QueryResponse</Name>
    <Content>       
        <Object>
            <Slot name="AddedValue">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>Value to Add</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Slot>
            <Slot name="languageCode">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>en-us</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Slot>                 
        </Object>
    </Content>
</XMLMessage>
```

Second Transformation, with the `<apply-templates>` above the added `<Slot>`, results in the `@Status` attribute being included, but the added `<Slot>` is now below the original node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="//Object[not(Slot/@name='AddedValue')]">      
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <Slot name="AddedValue">
            <ValueList>
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Value to Add'"/>
                </Value>
            </ValueList>
        </Slot>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<XMLMessage>
    <Name>QueryResponse</Name>
    <Content>       
        <Object status="Approved">
            <Slot name="languageCode">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>en-us</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Slot>                 
            <Slot name="AddedValue">
                <ValueList>
                    <Value>Value to Add</Value>
                </ValueList>
            </Slot>
        </Object>
    </Content>
</XMLMessage>
```

I would like to understand why the attribute does not come across with the first transformation. What attribute is it "trying" to get? The attribute of the "languageCode" `<Slot>`?

How could I get the "AddedValue" `<Slot>` above the "languageCode" `<Slot>` while retaining the `@Status` attribute?

Comment: You need a better testing environment - one that produces error messages.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I was using Notepad++ Add-In "XSLT Tools" to do the transformation. I'm a bit hamstrung by my work restrictions, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [XSLT specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#creating-attributes), adding an attribute to an element after children have been added to it is an error. Create all attributes first, then create the child nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="Object[not(Slot/@name='AddedValue')]">      
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <Slot name="AddedValue">
            <ValueList>
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Value to Add'"/>
                </Value>
            </ValueList>
        </Slot>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense to me. I was using Notepad++ Add-In "XSLT Tools" to do the transformation.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 (the old version which comes with Nodepad++) it's a "recoverable" error which means the processor can ignore the error and simply not write the attribute.